# I need connect mysql via ssh

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

is there a valid extension for connect mysql via ssh on visual code studio?
I can't find nothing!; 
I've been tryed with Mysql managment tool but seem there are not options for ssh

Answer (score 3):

I guess you mean that you want to connect to MySQL via an SSH tunnel.

I don't know any specific solution for visual studio code, but if you have an extension to browse your database (and it doesn't support SSH tunneling) on its own, you can just create a ssh tunnel by yourself. Just run:

```
ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 user@remotehost
```

And keep that session opened for the time you want to use your DB. Point your DB browser at `127.0.0.1:3306` and that's it.

Keep in mind that `127.0.0.1` in the example is the *host you're tunneling TO*, so if your MySQL server listens on, say, `1.3.3.7`, just do `-L 3306:1.3.3.7:3306`.

Comment: thank you  but i just looking for a solution out of the box